# Can I use two parameter event for one function?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, drop-down-menu, event-handling

What I want to do is change the url.

1. Replace the Object word with an event parameter called e1.
2. Replace the word field with the event parameter e2.

I know this code is not working.
But I don't know how to do it.

The following is my code that I just wrote.

```
function getAllFieldValue(e1,e2) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var url = 'test123.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v44.0/queryAll?q=SELECT Field FROM Object';
  var url = url.replace('Object',e1);
  var url = url.replace('Field',e2);
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,getUrlFetchOptions());
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);
  var fieldValues = data.records;

 for(var i=0;i<fieldValues.length;i++){
   var fieldValue = fieldValues[i].e;
   ss.getRange(i+1,1).setValue(fieldValue);
 }
}
```

I want to take the data from another database through this code and put it in the Google spreadsheet.

For e1, it means the object value selected in the dropbox.
For e2, it means the field of the object selected in the drop box.

Is there a way to use two event parameters for one function?
I look forward to hearing from you.

====================

Please understand that I am using a translator because I am not good at English.

Checking fieldValues[i] in Logger.log returns the following values:

```
[{
        attributes={
            type=Account, 
            url=/services/data/v44.0/sobjects/Account/0015i00000BS03VAAT
    }, 
            Name=University of Arizona
    }, 
    {
        attributes={
            type=Account, 
            url=/services/data/v44.0/sobjects/Account/0015i00000BS03TAAT
    }, 
            Name=United Oil & Gas Corp.
    }, 
    {
        attributes={
            type=Account, 
            url=/services/data/v44.0/sobjects/Account/0015i00000BS03ZAAT
    }, 
            Name=sForce

}]
```

The issues I am currently experiencing are as follows.
If I select 'Name' from the drop-down list, ec2 becomes 'Name'.
As far as I'm concerned,
var fieldName = fieldValues[i].e2 is
var fieldName = fieldValues[i].Name
It means that.

I think fieldValues[i].e2 should return the values of University of Arizona, United Oil & Gas Corp, sForce.
But in reality nothing is returned.

var fieldName = fieldValues[i].Name works properly.
I think there is a problem with fieldValues[i].e2

This is the problem I'm currently experiencing.

Comment: yes, you can call a function that takes two event parameters by calling it with two event parameters.

Comment: I thought that in your showing script, when the values of `e1` and `e2` are given, `url` can be replaced by `e1` and `e2`. So I cannot understand `I know this code is not working.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it? And also, I cannot understand `For e1, it means the object value selected in the dropbox. For e2, it means the field of the object selected in the drop box.`. Can I ask you about the detail of this?

Comment: How is the function be called?

Comment: @JaromandaX Thank you for your reply.
The problem is not url, but var fieldValue = fieldValues[i].e2;
The problem was that e2 was not working in .

Comment: @Tanaike  Thank you for your reply.
As you said, I confirmed that e1, e2 are working properly. However, var fieldValue = fieldValues[i].I checked that e2; is not working properly. (It is set to e, but it does not actually work if it is run with e2)
If you know the reason, can I know? Thank you for your help every time.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand `However, var fieldValue = fieldValues[i].I checked that e2; is not working properly. (It is set to e, but it does not actually work if it is run with e2)`. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal? For example, if you want to retrieve the specific values from the returned value of the API, I think that when you provide the sample input and output values you expect, it will help users think of the solution.

Comment: @Tanaike I added more detailed comments to the post about the problems I am currently experiencing.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your added information, how about modifying `var fieldName = fieldValues[i].e2` to `var fieldName = fieldValues[i][e2]`? But, if I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike Wow!
It works properly.
Thank you so much for your help every time.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Comment: @Tanaike
I didn't understand the meaning of posting it as an answer.
Can I just copy and paste the answers on my post?
Or is there a way to choose the answer as the answer?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. In that case, I think that posting a solution like to modify `var fieldName = fieldValues[i].e2` to `var fieldName = fieldValues[i][e2]` for achieving your goal might be useful.

Comment: @Tanaike I understand. I'll do that.
Thank you!

Comment: In this case, please post your added text as an answer by clicking "Post Your Answer".

Comment: @Tanaike Oh, I got it now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There was no problem with the parameters e1, e2, which I thought was a problem. The reason why the code did not work is because of the for loop `var fieldValue = fieldValues[i].e;` Because it didn't work properly.

```
var fieldName = fieldValues[i].e2
```

to

```
var fieldName = fieldValues[i][e2]
```

After modifying it like this, the code works properly.